# How I can select multiple nodes from a page by the order that appears in the page using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract multiple `HTML` nodes from a page in the same order that they appear in the page. because I want later to get just the 10 first nodes.

The problem is scrapy selector selects nodes in a random order, so when I  show the first 10 results, those results are not the 10 first nodes in the HTML page.

```
products = response.css("ul.items > li")[:10]
```

I expect to get 10 first products as in the `HTML` page, but what happened is that I get 10 random products from all the page.
is anyone has an idea on how I can select just the first nodes that I want?

Comment: Can not reproduce your problem. My guess is that the website you are scraping initially sends HTML with the products in the order you are seeing in scrapy, and then later reorders them with javascript to what you expected as a result.  
My fix in these cases is usually to use a headless browser for the scraping job. Bit of a hassle though. Maybe like this: https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash

Comment: Unless I'm understanding it terribly wrong, Scrapy's selectors are indeed designed to preserve the exact same order of nodes as appearing on the pages. Or to be precise: Scrapy itself does not do anything on node ordering, while the underlying `lxml` package is designed to persevere the order.
There're, though specific cases that you might observe "unordered" results, e.g. if the source HTML is indeed invalid and lxml tries to fix the issue.
Please provide further information, especially those that can help reproduce the issue (URL to a sample page, expected results, etc.).